# How to Use Mysql rand() result twice?

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax

Just like the below

```
UPDATE tableA
SET hit_count = hit_count + (SELECT FLOOR(5 + (RAND() * 6))) AS randVAlue, total_hit_count = total_hit_count + randVAlue
WHERE 1
```

I'd like to add a rand value but it should be applied two different column at once.
If I use two rand() function, it applies different rand result value.

The above statement results syntax error.
Please let me know what is the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same Random Value For ALL row

```
SET @varRan=FLOOR(5 + (RAND() * 6));
UPDATE tableA
SET hit_count = hit_count + @varRan, 
    total_hit_count = total_hit_count + @varRan
WHERE 1;
```

Different Random Value For Each row

```
UPDATE Table1
SET val1 = IFNULL(val1,0) + @varRan:= FLOOR(5 + (RAND() * 6)), 
val2 = IFNULL(val2,0) + @varRan;
```

Comment: According to this code, all the rows are updated by @varRan at once, Is there other way to update all the rows with all the different random value?

Comment: Try the 2nd Query @Kabkee

Comment: wow !! never seen before like the above. :) Thank you for your additional comment. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a mysql variable and assign it the random value. Then you can use it as may times as you want in your logic.

```
SET @randomNumber = RAND();
UPDATE table SET field1 = @randomNumber, field2 = @randomNumber;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and/or **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.